# Migrate axon framework to Java 17

Tags: spring-boot, java-17, axon-framework

I am migrating to `Spring Boot 3` and `Java 17` and using `Axon` framework `4.8.0`. When I try to startup the project I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
```

Afaik, javax is no longer used and `jakarta.*` must be used. How can I migrate axon then?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be some old legacy library which was using javax.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).